# composer dump-autoload do nothing

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to execute the command `composer dump-autoload` on a Laravel project, but it does nothing. It only writes `Generating optimized autoload files`, then stops.

I tried it on an other project, and it worked well (discovered packages, and so on).

I also tried it after updating composer (`composer self-update`), after checking that my composer.json is right (`composer validate`). Nothing changed...

The command `composer update` works well on the update part, but does the same when it arrives to the dump-autoload one.

Does someone have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: ```use composer dump-autoload -o``` with an ```-o```
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md

Answer (score 1):

Check your `composer.json`, `pre-install-cmd` and `post-autoload-dump` was missing.

Your `scripts` should look like this

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    }        
}
```

If the problem persists, run `composer dump-autoload -vvv` and check detailed errors.

Comment: My file was missing "post-autoload-dump" and the method "postAutoloadDump". I added them from an other project.
Now saying that "php artisan package:discover" is not existing, but my current project is on Laravel 5.4, so I think that's why.

Comment: try run manually in your console `php artisan package:discover`. Also, check is you have `artisan` file doing `ls -la | grep artisan`